# Why CAST function behaves different when called within a sproc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, converters

When I call the CONVERT function with the style 127, from management studio like below:

```
select top 1 * , CONVERT(varchar(255), ManufactureTime, 127)as ManufactureTime
from Machines
```

Output for the ManucaftureTime is: 
'2015-06-08 10:00:01'

However when I do the same call from a sproc and when I execute the sproc I get in a different style:

'2015-06-08**T**10:00:01' (That is ISO8601 with time zone Z.)

Any idea why the behavior of CONVERT differs when called from stored-procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Try to display the execution in text instead of a grid in SSMS and check the results.

Comment: Style 127 should [always](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) generate the T - so there's more than just the query you're showing us in the first example.

Comment: `DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2015-06-08 10:00:01';
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), @dt, 127) AS ManufactureTime` - in sql server 2012 produces a value including the T: `2015-06-08T00:00:00`